Rigorous Justification for "Only Available Tensor"
In many instances, for example in particle physics, some argument of the following form is given: This rank 2 tensor we have here is a function of some vector (say $p^\mu$), so it must be some linear combination of $g^{\mu \nu}$ and $p^\mu p^\nu$. The most prominent example is probably the hadronic tensor, but that sort of reasoning seems to appear everywhere in theoretical physics. Is there any way to rigorously justify that? I don't see why you couldn't take any 2 by 2 matrix and fix it in some inertial system and transform normally into any other inertial system that you might be interested in, then you'd get a rank 2 tensor. The notion that something is the only available tensor is somewhat plausible but I'm really uncertain how to actually prove that. 
I found a similar question here What is the reasoning behind these arguments in QFT? that was never properly answered.
Just to give concrete examples:

Why is the hadronic tensor necessarily of the form $$W^{\mu \nu} = a \cdot g^{\mu \nu} + b \cdot p^\mu p^\nu + c \cdot p^\mu q^\nu + d \cdot q^\mu p^\nu + e \cdot q^\mu q^\nu~?$$
Why does the expectation value of the potential in QED have to vanish? Why is $$\langle\Omega|{A^\mu(x)}|{\Omega}\rangle = \langle\Omega|{A^\mu(0)}|{\Omega}\rangle = 0~?$$
Why is the polarization sum $\sum_s \vec \varepsilon^s_j \vec \varepsilon^s_{j'}$ necessarily of the form $$\sum_s \vec \varepsilon^s_j \vec \varepsilon^s_{j'} = A \delta_{j j'} + B k_j k_{j'}~?$$ I know different arguments why the polarization sum has to have the value it has (using that the epsilons and k form an orthonormal basis), but just for completeness.


A simpler version of the same argument in electrostatics would be: the electric field $E_i$ due to a single point charge is a function of the radial vector $r_i$ that points away from that point charge, $E_i = E(r) r_i$. (a) What kind of rigorous argument would you give in that case? Can you extend it to the case you're interested in? (b) Can you see why your "counterexample", which in this situation would be "pick a specific set of $x, y, z$ axes, specify the components of a vector, then rotate that vector to any other frame and let $E_i$ depend on that vector" does not work here?

FWIW, this is known as invariant theory.

Note that in the first example we need a separate motivation for how, if at all, the scalars $a$ to $e$ can depend on $p^2,,p\cdot q,,q^2$.
